# Recommendation request re Fitch notation

Tags: logic, reference-request

I am looking for books, articles, and websites that are basic introductions to the logic notation system created by Frederic Fitch. Recommendations welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned Fitch-style natural deduction from Teller's *A Modern Formal Logic Primer*, which is freely available [here](http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/pdf/). Teller goes through the motivations for specific formal decisions and outlines the strengths and weaknesses of formal reasoning. It's pretty good. I know of at least one intro to logic class that uses it as a textbook.

If you're going to TeX anything I recommend browsing [LaTeX for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/). The specific package I use, thanks to this page, is [fitch.sty](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/fitch/).